# I want to find similarity between two different images

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have got two photos, one of them has got good resolution taken by camera and another one is noisy and captured from a video.

How can I compare them? Is there any software for this?

Comment: which parameter do you want to compare? resolution / dimension / degree of noise ? Degree of noise is hard to detect.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), it's got a Windows version, and I've seen it used for image comparison purposes. There are some good examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't tell you the software, but I can most certainly help you with some technical know-how(s) on this whole problem, so that you can run a quick search and get your hands on relevant tools ...

--- As a preprocessing step, convert both your images in raw RGB format. bmp will ought to do you fine and convert both the images to same resolution. I also assume that by `resolution difference` in your question, you mean quality difference, i.e. one image has vivid and sharp colors and that other is slightly flushed and blurry (the one taken from video) ---

1) Firstly, if you want to compare content, then make sure that both your images have same content, and that only difference is that of resolution (which you have eradicated in pre-processing step), color-depth and noise. If the images have different content, or if one image is the cropped version of other image, you can't compare the images as a whole, but rather you will have to carefully section the image (cropping in arbitrary shape) to get hold of right areas of both images to compare.

2) Now, lets say everything is upbeat in view of first step, Now, try some Image viewer having some Image processing capabilities (like Irfanview, ACDSEE etc. ) and try adding noise to the second image. There are various type of noise(es), so try some noise-models that are provided in the tool. For sake of clarity, observe the change in visual similarity (dissimilarity) among your images as and when you're applying these models. You can also try other transformations like, blurring, sharpening etc.

3) If this doesn't work, then try this. Try transforming both the images in gray scale and continue decreasing the bit-depth to bitone image (i.e. black and white). I don't know if the tool can allow you to do this, but search for some tool with the keyword "converting image to grayscale + decreasing color-depth". Needless to say, for any transformation done, you will have to keep observing/tracking (either visually or programaticaly) the similarity (or dissimilarity).

- Now, let us see why the last technique has good chances of working. I don't know if you would understand this but it is a simple idea, so try and follow.

-An raw image is nothing but a matrix of 24 bit values (no. of bits can actually vary but the idea is same), where 8 bits are for Red, 8 for Blue and 8 for green. There is one such 24 bit value for each pixel and hence, when you have to find similarity between two images, you compare two images pixel by pixel, for their similarity in these 24 bit values. Now, since you say that both the images have same content but one has slight noise and low resolution (which means it is blurry and flushed), this basically means that level of detail in that image is less compare to other. This further means that for each pixel, bit values are not scaled as wide apart as they are for high quality images in RGB spectrum and hence, take only limited values for each of these components. In other words the detail in the high quality image is due to 255 possible levels of red, green and blue made possible by using 8 bits for each of them. Where as, in other image (blurry and flushed) this detail is not captured mainly because lot of lower order bits for each RGB are either zero or non-existent ( possibly because the image was originally captured with only 4 color-bits and then scaled to 8 bits). Hence, if I methodically start deleting the lower order bits (by deleting I mean setting them to zero), my good quality image will tend to take same level or colors as my other blurry image. In technical terms, I'll be deleting some visual planes, to decrease the detail in the image and this is exactly what you want. And finally, since you've ensured that the content of the images is same, if you compare them now, they will match with high probability.

Regards
Vaid, Abhishek
AViD